# How to use my own findById declaration instead of the one by Spring Data?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to upgrade spring-boot version to 2.1.2 and we are using Spring data JPA, for DB operations.

In many places we are invoking `findById(Id)` method which is changed to `Optional<T> findById(Id).orElse(null)`, this throws me compile time errors with my existing `findById(Id)` whose return type is not `Optional<>`.

To overcome this scenario, I implemented a custom interface which extends `BaseJpaRepository`, but here the method name and arguments are same in both old and new version of spring Boot.

I tried to call as below

```
@NoRepositoryBean

public interface CustomBaseJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>  {

    default  T findById(ID id) {
        return (T) findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

But it's trying to loop and I'm not sure how to invoke `CrudRepository.findById(Id)` from my `findById()` so that, I need to do very minimal changes.

Comment: I have same issue with save() even this is changed to saveAll() which is looking for <Entity> List<Entity> SaveAll(Iterable<Entity> entities). @ Jens  Schauder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend renaming your existing method to a different name. 
For example `findByIdNullable`.
With a modern IDE this should be an easy change.